# Socket Connection Aborted While calling Wcf Function

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to get list of objects through WCF service. Some simple methods works fine. But when i try to get list of objects

I get the following error.

Error:The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:59:59.9949990'. 
Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Here is client configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ISurveyService" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000"
            maxArrayLength="200000000" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ISurveyService1" />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8523/SurveyService" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ISurveyService" contract="SurveyApp.SurveyService.ISurveyService"
        name="NetTcpBinding_ISurveyService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8523/SurveyService" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ISurveyService1" contract="ServiceReference.ISurveyService"
        name="NetTcpBinding_ISurveyService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And this is the service library configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ISurveyService" openTimeout="00:10:00"
                   closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                   sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                   receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                  maxBufferSize="20000000"
                  maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                   maxArrayLength="200000000"
                   maxStringContentLength="200000000" />
        </binding>

      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1Behavior"
        name="SurveyApp.SurveyService.SurveyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ISurveyService"
          contract="SurveyApp.SurveyService.ISurveyService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/SurveyService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is my service contract:

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISurveyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<Question> GetAllQuestions();

        [OperationContract]
        Test GetElement();
    }
```

And this is data contract class

```
   public partial class Question
    {

        public Question()
        {
            this.QuestionOptions = new HashSet<QuestionOption>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like server is not able to process the call. What do WCF logs contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuestionOption class has a member of type Question, so there was a recursive call during serialization, so timeoout occurs.